# IAR C/C++ comparsion operator behaviour

Tags: c++, embedded, stm32, iar

I have following define:

```
#define DEVICE_ID   ((uint8_t)0x3f)
```

and I have following function:

```
void LIS3DSH_Init(LIS3DSH_InitTypeDef* LIS3DSH_InitStruct)
{
//    uint8_t ctrl=0x00;
    uint8_t ident=0x00;

    LIS3DSH_LowLevel_Init();

    LIS3DSH_Read(&ident,
                 LIS3DSH_WHOAMI_REG_ADDR,
                 1);

    if(DEVICE_ID==ident)
    {
        // LIS3DSH detected
    }
    else
    {
        // LIS3DSH not detected

        failureHandler();
    }

}   // LIS3DSH_Init
```

Now, if I go step-by-step in this function, the ident variable gets value 0x3f after LIS3DSH_Read function call, which is ok. My question is, why the hell if clause jumps to failureHandler? The values of DEVICE_ID and ident are the same - both are 0x3f, if should not jump to failureHanlder(). I am working on LIS3DSH accelerator library using IAR C/C++ and STM32F4 Discovery Board. Here is a screenshot of situation:[image: If clause going wrong?!]

Comment: Check for another define of DEVICE_ID masking this one.

Comment: I've commented the line that defines DEVICE_ID in my code and then the projects does not build since DEVICE_ID is not found.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the pseudo-code you are showing to us. Can you add more of the *real* code?

Comment: I have updated original post for @DanielFrey

Comment: If this is your real code and the debugger shows 0x3f for the value, then I'm at a total loss as to why the compiler is calling failureHandler(). Sorry.

Comment: Can you check that the hardware is not faulty? Is the Sun unusually active today? Is anyone baking hot pockets on a badly shielded microwave oven nearby? Anyone generating sparks (electric shaver, blender, etc) too close to the device? Did one of your coworkers play a prank on you by sticking some neodymium magnets near your hard drive?

Comment: @DanielKO, how should I check the hardware?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih: doesn't it come with any diagnostics tool? Don't you have a second board to try it on? In my experience, if you can't even rely on the compiler/hardware performing integer comparison, either you wrote such a bad code you are corrupting the entire program to the point not even the debugger can make sense of it, or you have faulty hardware.

Comment: I did not write bad code, I am following code practice from LIS302DL example library.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly language listing?  Sometimes the compiler my "optimize-out" code because it would never be called.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you for your hint, it was optimization! :D I've turned it off and now if clause works ok! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should type-cast the `if(DEVICE_ID==ident)` to be `if( (uint8_t)DEVICE_ID == (uint8_t)ident)`

This has been an issue for me in the past.

And yes, declare ident as volatile, and for debugging purposes, try adding a delay before the comparison via a for-loop with `__no_operation();` inside it. Note that there are 2 underscores in front of that, not 1 (intrinsic NOP instruction), and that a single NOP takes roughly ~29ns on a 168MHz board, measured via scope.

Also, since you have IAR, you might as well pop open the "assembly" view and look at what registers and/or constants are actually being compared. Open the "register" view as well...so you can see the register values themselves.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but in my case, optimizations were the problem. I disabled all optimiztions and now it's ok.

Comment: There should be no need to make `ident` volatile. `LIS3DSH_WHOAMI_REG_ADDR` o.t.o.h should be volatile. How is `LIS3DSH_Read` defined? Function or macro?

Comment: Sure, good question.  Yea sometimes optimizations cause the compiler to cut corners on comparisons, and casting was my issue once. It may let you keep optimizations on. Take care

Answer (score 1):

Is the function

```
failureHandler()
```

processed? 
If not, the view of the debugger is just confusing due to compiler optimizations.
It is likely that the optimized code uses a common "return" code for both the
good case and the failure case. The debugger stops at the "exit" of the failure path even
in good case.

Comment: Yes, failureHandler() is processed, the orange leds is blinking. And I have disabled all optimizations.

Comment: Strange. Is there an interrupt routine that can change the value of "ident"? Maybe "ident" gets the value 0x3F after(!) the "if" test. (just wild guesses ;-))